# How does Xcode determine the location of a source file in Build Phases -> Compile Sources?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

When you add a source file to the `Compiled Sources` section of a target's `Build Phase` it describes the location of each file in light gray next to the files:

```
...in ../../shared_source/controllers
```

How is Xcode create this string? I'm having trouble with a project that gets it "wrong" -- seems to be a directory relative to someone else's environment, but not mine. Removing and re-adding the source does not help, nor does any amount of cleaning.

Comment: Managed to fix the problem I was seeing by the location drop down on the file and changing to from "Relative to Group" to "Relative to Project". Would still love to know the precise way this path is created.

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding the source to your project, do you check the "copy items into destination group's folder" option? If you don't, XCode is just pulling a reference from wherever the file is, without actually copying it into the project. This works fine until the original file gets moved. In my experience you generally want to copy.

Comment: Yes, although we discovered that even that can break if you set up your environment in a crazy enough way.